# Is Flash Builder standalone Eclipse Indigo or Helios

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder

I have Flash Builder 4.6 installed and I'm trying to install the Eclipse Marketplace Client. It gives me update locations for Indigo and Helios. Which Eclipse is Flash Builder 4.6 built on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash Builder 4.6 runs on Eclipse Indigo, but still supports Helios as a plug-in.

```
Eclipse Platform
Version: 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f
Build id: I20110613-1736
```

[Flash Builder 4.6 release notes](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/release-note/flash-builder-4-6-release.html) state:

> Flash Builder 4.6 supports installation as a plugin to an existing
>   Eclipse instance
>
> *PC:* (Note: Your copy of Eclipse must be version 3.6/3.6.1/3.6.2/3.7,
>   32-bit and must contain a folder named “dropins”)
>
> *Mac:* (Note: Your copy of Eclipse must be version 3.6/3.6.1/3.6.2/3.7,
>   32-bit, Cocoa, containing a folder named “dropins”).

Flash Builder 4.6 updated to Eclipse 3.7, per the [What's new in Flash Builder 4.6](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/whatsnew-flashbuilder-46.html)

> When you install Flash Builder 4.6, you'll notice that an updated
>   version of Eclipse 3.7 is included. However, Flash Builder 4.6 still
>   supports Eclipse 3.6 as a plug-in in case you aren't ready to upgrade.